# char constant display in Javadoc "Constant Field Values" page

Tags: java, constants, javadoc

Is there a way I can get the generated "Constant Field Values" page to use readable characters instead of integers for `char` type constants?

For instance, if a class contains the following constants:

```
public static final char YES = 'Y';
public static final char NO  = 'N';
public static final char ERROR  = 'E';
```

I want the javadoc constant field values page to have the character representation ('Y', 'N', 'E') not the integer version (69, 78, 89).

We have hundreds of these so I don't want to have to go and add some specific javadoc comment to each occurence (e.g. using `@value`).

---

**UPDATE:** Thanks to SubOptimal's answer below, I managed to use the version 1.6 source code for the `ConstantsSummaryWriterImpl` that I found [here](http://j6a.ru/_constants_summary_writer_impl_8java_source.html), to modify the `writeValue` method as follows:

```
private void writeValue(FieldDoc member) {
    tdAlign("right");
    code();
    if ("char".equals(member.type().toString())) {
        print(Util.escapeHtmlChars("'" + ((char) ((Integer)member.constantValue()).intValue()) + "'"));

    } else {
        print(Util.escapeHtmlChars(member.constantValueExpression()));
    }
    codeEnd();
    tdEnd();
}
```

Once this class is compiled up and used to override the one in 'tools.jar', the `char` constants are output as the character, not the number.

Comment: You were hasty in awarding the bounty early. There is a proper way of doing this, and it isn't hacking the existing javadoc tool

Comment: @Bohemian care to elaborate? Or are you just going to dangle that one just out of reach? I awarded the bounty based on the answers I had (which included one from you), and the fact that I was going to be away from my computer from Friday until today. Is this just sour grapes because your answer didn't get the bounty, or do you have an actual solution?

Comment: I researched this a bit. The "right" way to do it is to create a custom class to handle the tag and tell java to use it for the `@value` tag via a command line option. I would extend the base class using the decorator pattern - doing custom behaviour for a `char` const but deferring to the super class's impl for everything else. Hacking the base class is a poor solution because every time you upgrade the JDK you have to re-edit the base class.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't that mean I would have to be using the `@value` tags? Which I'm not.

Comment: If you're not using `@value`, I would still try to find a solution that uses a custom class that extends ConstantsSummaryWriterImpl or similar. The point is, you ideally want a solution that's portable between java versions.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, Glen, and I totally agree with you. However, after a day or so of searching the net, I have still not found any solution to overriding the ConstantsSummaryWriter doclet. And the lack of answers here seems to indicate that there may not be a 'standard' way to do it. I have certainly added an issue in our in-house JIRA system to deal with this, so that I don't forget to revisit this when things aren't so hectic around here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by tweaking `javadoc` itself a little bit.

1. get the source for javadoc tool (don't worry we need only one file to tweak ;-) )
   I took the file `langtools-ce654f4ecfd8.tar.gz` from here [JDK 7 langtools source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/langtools/shortlog/ce654f4ecfd8)
2. extract the file `ConstantsSummaryWriterImpl.java`
3. modify the method `getValue(FieldDoc member)`

   ```
   ...
   private Content getValue(FieldDoc member) {
       Content valueContent;
       if ("char".equals(member.type().toString())) {
           valueContent = new StringContent("'" 
               + (char) ((Integer) member.constantValue()).intValue()
               + "'"
           );
       } else {
           valueContent = new StringContent(member.constantValueExpression());
       }
       Content code = HtmlTree.CODE(valueContent);
       return HtmlTree.TD(HtmlStyle.colLast, code);
   }
   ...
   ```
4. compile the changed file
   `javac -cp ${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar -d . ConstantsSummaryWriterImpl.java`
5. run the javadoc
   `javadoc -J-Xbootclasspath/p:.;${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar -d api/ Scratch.java`

the file **Scratch.java**

```
public class Scratch {
    public static final char YES = 'Y';
    public static final char NO  = 'N';
    public static final char ERROR  = 'E';
}
```

Comment: This looks like a possible solution, thanks. I will gives this a try in the next day or so and give you the bounty if it works for us.

Comment: By the way, would this work OK if the char value is not a printable character? We don't have any of those ourselves, but I'm just thinking if other people see this and they have char values that are below 32.

Comment: OK, I found a 1.6 version of this class [here](http://j6a.ru/_constants_summary_writer_impl_8java_source.html), but it doesn't have a method called 'getValue'. However, it does have a method called 'writeValue' which seems to output the `member.constantValueExpression()`. I see this is actually a doclet. Is there anyway to 'override' this doclet with my own one, instead of actually modifying the tools.jar? There seems to be very little documentation of this on the internet.

Comment: Works like a charm! (See my update above) You win the prize!  :-)

Comment: @DuncanKinnear Here is a documentation about writing your own doclets. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html

Comment: Yes, I had seen that page in my google travels, but it's still not obvious from that if you can override a specific standard doclet like the Constants Summary Writer.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. Unfortunately, javadoc is a bit dense in this respect - a `char` is a *numeric* primitive.

You could work around it by using Strings

```
public static final String YES = "Y";
public static final String NO  = "N";
public static final String ERROR  = "E";
```

and refactoring your code to use a utility method where you previously used the char constants:

```
public static char asChar(String str) {
    if (str.length() != 1) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException(str + " must be exactly 1 character long");
    }
    return str.charAt(0);
}
```

eg

```
if (ch == asChar(ERROR))
```

which would hopefully make this tolerable.

Note the parameter checking to make sure you don't accidentally declare one of the Strings with other than a single character.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really interested in any solution that requires refactoring production code. We're way too busy to have to deal with that kind of stuff at the moment. I just want these constant values more visible for our support department.

Comment: Print out an ASCII chart and pin it up in each support person's cubicle.

Answer (score 0):

Could some postprocessing be a feasible option?

This program walks through the file tree and processes all files that are called `constant-values.html`. They are loaded using the [Jericho HTML Parser](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html). The table that is called  `constantValuesContainer` is examined: If the first column contains the text `static final char`, and the value in the last column is an integer value, then it is replaced with the appropriate character.

Note that this is only a sketch (but at least, tested on "its own" JavaDoc ;-)). The conditions for the replacement could be refined. For example, the matching for the text in the first column should be made more robust (for the case that someone creates a class that starts with `char`....). The replacement should probably be done only when the integer value is a valid *ASCII* character, to avoid messing up constants like `static final char CHAR_MAX = 0xFFFF`. But adjustments like these should be easy, if (!) such a postprocessing step is a possible way to go.

```
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.List;

import net.htmlparser.jericho.Element;
import net.htmlparser.jericho.OutputDocument;
import net.htmlparser.jericho.Segment;
import net.htmlparser.jericho.Source;

public class ConstantsTest
{
    private static final char CHAR_A = 'A';
    protected static final char CHAR_B = 'B';
    static final char CHAR_C = 'C';
    public static final char CHAR_D = 'D';
    public static final char CHAR_E = 'E';
    public static final char CHAR_F = 'F';
    public static final int INT_65 = 65;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
    {
        Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("./doc/");
        Files.walkFileTree(path, new FileProcessor());
    }

    static class FileProcessor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path>
    {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attributes)
        {
            //System.out.println("Visit "+file+" name '"+file.getFileName()+"'");
            if (file.getFileName().toString().equals("constant-values.html"))
            {
                process(file);
            }
            return CONTINUE;
        }
    }

    private static void process(Path file) 
    {
        try
        {
            doProcess(file);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void doProcess(Path file) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Processing "+file);
        Source source=new Source(file.toFile());
        OutputDocument outputDocument=new OutputDocument(source);
        for (Element element : source.getAllElementsByClass("constantValuesContainer"))
        {
            List<Element> colFirsts = element.getAllElementsByClass("colFirst");
            List<Element> colLasts = element.getAllElementsByClass("colLast");
            for (int i=0; i<colFirsts.size(); i++)
            {
                Element colFirst = colFirsts.get(i);
                Segment colFirstContent = colFirst.getContent();
                String colFirstText = colFirstContent.getTextExtractor().toString();

                // TODO Generalize this according to your needs,
                // maybe with some RegEx...
                if (colFirstText.contains("static final char"))
                {
                    Element colLast = colLasts.get(i);
                    List<Element> children = colLast.getAllElements("code");
                    if (children.size() == 1)
                    {
                        Element child = children.get(0);
                        Segment childContent = child.getContent();
                        String childText = childContent.getTextExtractor().toString();
                        try
                        {
                            int value = Integer.parseInt(childText);
                            outputDocument.replace(childContent, String.valueOf((char)value));
                        }
                        catch (NumberFormatException e)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Value is not a number: "+childText+", ignoring");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        outputDocument.writeTo(
            new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file.toFile())));
        System.out.println("Processing "+file+" DONE");
    }


}
```

Comment: Post-processing may be possible, but it would have to fit in with our Jenkins build environment which generates the Javadoc every night. I was hoping someone might be able to tell me this was possible with doclets or something similar.